# Error with pointers in recv() function

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am doing socket programming for achieve communication between different entities in my application. When sending a message, I prefix the message with the length of the message and I terminate it with \0. I have recv() in a loop as follows:

```
void receive(int socket)
{
    int num_of_bytes_read = 0,  msg_len;
    char *msg = NULL, *msg_p = NULL;
    char recv_buf[MAX_LEN]; 

    while(num_of_bytes_read = recv(socket, recv_buf, MAX_LEN, 0))
    {
        if(msg == NULL)
        {
            memcpy(&msg_len, message, 4);
            msg_len = ntohl(msg_len);

            if((msg = (char *)(sizeof(char) * msg_len)) == NULL)
                systemError("Could not receive new message\n");

            printf("%p\n", msg);  /* prints 0xe!! Why is the address not 4B long??*/
            msg_p = msg;
        }

        if(memcpy(&msg_p, recv_buf, num_of_bytes_read) == NULL)
            systemError("memcpy failed in receive()\n");

        msg_p += num_of_bytes_read;
    }


    printf("%p\n", msg);                    /* prints (nil) !!!!!*/
    printf("%p\n", msg + sizeof(uint32_t)); /* prints 0x4 */

    /* pass the a pointer to the beginning of the message skipping msg_len*/
    int res = processMessage(msg + sizeof(uint32_t));
 }
```

**When I run the program I obviously get segmentation fault with the following error:
message=0x4**

What is wrong with **msg**?? Can someone please help.

Comment: Unrelated: That is the last way you *ever* want to check if a `recv` worked. The function returns `-1` on error, and will still pass your while-condition. Then consider what the rest of that code does with `-1` for the `num_of_bytes_read` value.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(num_of_bytes_read = recv(socket, recv_buf, MAX_LEN, 0))
```

This is already wrong. You should test for > 0. If `num_of_bytes` is zero you should close the socket, and if it is -1 you should log the associated `errno,` e.g. with `perror(),` and close the socket, and in both cases stop reading.

```
    if(msg == NULL)
    {
        memcpy(&msg_len, message, 4);
```

As long as `message` points to four bytes of addressable memory this will succeed. You have provided no information on the point. The purpose remains obscure.

```
        msg_len = ntohl(msg_len);
```

Here you are assuming that `message` pointed to four bytes that magically contain an `int` that has magically been set to a value you are prepared to regard as a message length. Why, I don't know. Again you have provided no information on the point.

```
        if((msg = (char *)(sizeof(char) * msg_len)) == NULL)
```

This is complete nonsense. Is there a `malloc()` missing in there somewhere?

```
            systemError("Could not receive new message\n");
```

A meaningless error message. The problem appears to be about allocating memory, but it's anybody's guess. It certainly has nothing to do with receiving messages.

```
        printf("%p\n", msg);  /* prints 0xe!! Why is the address not 4B long??*/
```

Here you appear to think the address should be 4B long. I don't know why.

```
    if(memcpy(&msg_p, recv_buf, num_of_bytes_read) == NULL)
```

You are copying data to the *address* of `msg_p.` This doesn't make sense. Also, at this point `num_of_bytes_read` could be -1 due to your incorrect loop condition above, so anything could happen, including trying to copy 0xffffffff bytes.

```
        systemError("memcpy failed in receive()\n");
```

The only way you can get to this line is if `msg_p`'s *address* was null, which is impossible. Remove the `&` from `&msg_p` in the `memcpy()` call. Now you can only get to this `systemError()` call if `msg_p` was zero, which would already have caused a SEGV, so you still can't get to this line. A bit of *preventative* coding is indicated here.

```
    msg_p += num_of_bytes_read;
```

Again `num_of_bytes_read` could be -1 at this point, sending your pointer backwards instead of forwards.

```
printf("%p\n", msg);                    /* prints (nil) !!!!!*/
```

Nil indicates that `msg` was zero.

```
printf("%p\n", msg + sizeof(uint32_t)); /* prints 0x4 */
```

0x4 again indicates that `msg` was zero.

You need to improve your code in the areas indicated.

Answer (score 2):

`msg = (char *)(sizeof(char) * msg_len)`

You are setting `msg` to some address based on the `msg_len`. Not actually anything to do with where the msg resides in memory...

Comment: +1 Yet-another reason you never cast malloc in C, though I must admit this is the first time I've ever seen it hide the fact the engineer *forgot to type the word **`malloc`***!! That's almost worth bonus points for originality.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good pickup - I started to look at what the code should be then got distracted. Looks like you've nailed it. Of course OPs code is still missing a +1 to allow for the '\0'.

Comment: Seriously. I wanna favorite this just to show a colleague at work tomorrow. I've *never* seen that before in 26 years of professional engineering, and I've seen a *lot*.